# building a scatter plot with grouped categories on the x-axis with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I’m looking to build a scatter plot with grouped categories on the x-axis. I’ve built this type of plot before with highcharts.js, and an example of a such a plot is [here](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories). Is it possible to build this type of scatter plot with d3.js? I have a normal d3 scatter plot in a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Q567s/431/), and it has a simple data object that can be grouped on the x-axis by the ‘tier’ and the 'price' variable. Has anyone used d3 to build a scatter plot with multiple variables on the x-axis? any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

example data object:

```
var chocolates = [{
    "name": "Dairy Milk",
    "manufacturer": "cadbury",
    "tier": 4,
    "price": 45,
    "rating": 2
}, {
    "name": "Galaxy",
    "manufacturer": "Nestle",
    "tier": 2,
    "price": 42,
    "rating": 3
}, {
    "name": "Lindt",
    "manufacturer": "Lindt",
    "tier": 1,
    "price": 80,
    "rating": 4
}, {
    "name": "Hershey",
    "manufacturer": "Hershey",
    "tier": 5,
    "price": 40,
    "rating": 1
}, {
    "name": "Dolfin",
    "manufacturer": "Lindt",
    "tier": 1,
    "price": 90,
    "rating": 5
}, {
    "name": "Bournville",
    "manufacturer": "cadbury",
    "tier": 4,
    "price": 70,
    "rating": 2
}];
```

Comment: do you want a scatter plot? or a grouped bar chart as result?

Comment: scatter plot @torresomar

Comment: so this example you posted of highcharts is a what you want http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories?

Comment: the highcharts example shows an example of how the X-axis should look like @torresomar

Comment: so you want a grouped axis in scattered data? how is the grouping going to work when you have something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Q567s/432/